# C# filesystem watcher - find user who triggered events

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I built a windows service which monitors our shared network folders(NAS). i was able to write logs to event viewer when any folder is created, renamed, deleted. my ultimate goal would be to find "**By whom was that folder created or renamed or deleted**" and include their username or LanID to the event viewer log.

I'm just looking for leads on how to approach on next steps. Below is my present code.

```
    public partial class NasFolderMonitor : ServiceBase
{
    public const string MyServiceName = "NASFolderWatcher";
    private System.Diagnostics.EventLog eventLog;

    public NasFolderMonitor()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        eventLog = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog();
        eventLog.Source = "NasMonitorLog";
        eventLog.Log = "NasMonitorLog";
    }

    public void NASFolderWatcher()
    {
        if (!EventLog.SourceExists("NasMonitorLog"))
        {
            EventLog.CreateEventSource("NASFolderWatcher", "NasMonitorLog");
        }

        // Create a new FileSystemWatcher with the path
        FileSystemWatcher NasWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher("Share Path here");
        NasWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
        NasWatcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        NasWatcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        NasWatcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        NasWatcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnChanged);

        // Begin watching
        NasWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        NASFolderWatcher();
        eventLog.WriteEntry("Monitoring Started");
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        eventLog.WriteEntry("Monitoring Stopped");
    }

    public void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        WatcherChangeTypes wct = e.ChangeType; 
        eventLog.WriteEntry(e.ChangeType.ToString() + "-" + e.FullPath);
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't be possible directly from .NET, and I'm honestly not sure how it's done in Windows, but you may want to look at the SysInternals Process Monitor utility for hints.

Comment: Windows audit policy can help you. http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Auditing_Windows_Server_2008_File_and_Folder_Access

Comment: @JianpingLiu i am not able to add audit policy because it is already configured in group policy for only failure event. which doesnt really help me here. isn't there another way other than audit policy?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will solve your problem completely, but you may be able to get who is owner (hence creator?) of the file/folder etc. I don't have a NAS running but try below code,it works on local machine:

```
var fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(@"c:\temp\client_id.json");
var ac = fi.GetAccessControl();
var user=ac.GetOwner(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount));

Console.WriteLine(user.Value);
```

Comment: my main goal would be to protect existing folders and files, Creating folders or files is perk i would like to add along with the other monitor filters. can you give any other ideas where i can monitor the folder and create event when any user makes any type of change.

Comment: If you have domain controller, I think your best bet is to configure this stuff in active directory so that people cannot modify or remove stuff.

Comment: we are in spot where we have different user groups who have access to that NAS share location and cant really touch the option of modifying the elevations. instead want to see who is actually making the changes because it is hard to reach out to all users asking if they made any changes.